# Adding a "-" sign in each line of a .txt file using Python

Tags: python, position, character, txt

I have a text file with about 5 million lines and each line contains three numbers, like for example:

```
33.56 77.32 12.54
```

The numbers always have the same length.

Now I have to add a minus sign before the last number to get the following output:

```
33.56 77.32 -12.54
```

How can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("filename.csv") as fh: 
    for line in fh: 
        line = line.strip()
        print(line[:12] + "-" + line[12:])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to write this directly into a new .txt file instead of as output in python?

Comment: Pleased to be of help, if you're satisfied with the answer could you accept it please?

Comment: @Kyahna A quick Google will turn up tons of information on writing to a file in Python. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) is a quick link; essentially, create and open the new file, write each line to it, then close it.